How to write logs to Azure blob user wise
In ASP.NET Core Web API, I need to write the logs to a separate folder for each users.
Suppose user1 logs in, when he accessing any actions, inside action by using logger, I am writing logs. These logs should placed under each user separately like user1/2024/07/31/log_1.log.
This will be the user1 july 31st log file.

Azure Blob Storage uses Containers to put all the blobs which works like folders, and we can upload blobs to containers based on business logic. In your scenario, I'm afraid Blob might not be a good option for storing logs because log files requires high frequency write opreation. Then you need to create file folder or each user every day which will create so many containers which is also not a good option for logging. I prefer to have log files for each day and do filters in log files.

In the meantime, since you already prepare to use Azure Service, I recommend azure application insights + azure monitor which is designed for log and log query, these are out-of-box feature.
